# Filling gaps when numpy reshape fails

Tags: python, numpy, reshape, valueerror

My goal is to create a heatmap. However,I have an issue with numpy's `reshape` method. And I wonder whether there is a nice way to fill the "gaps" that lead to this error message:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 4 into shape (4,4)
```

```
data_a = [[27, 6, 9944.93, 9944.93], [176, 30, 16345.47, 16345.47], [251, 18, 14242.78, 14242.78], [102, 42, 17085.14, 17085.14]]

data_b = [[15, 10, 10476.73, 10476.73], [15, 11, 9273.67, 9273.67], [16, 10, -3015.27, -3015.27], [16, 11, -9242.03, -9242.03]]
```

This is the code sippet:

```
    data = np.array(data_a)
    x = np.unique(data[:, 1].astype(int))
    y = np.unique(data[:, 0].astype(int))
    val = data[:, 3].reshape(len(y), len(x)) #code stops here
    min_val_ndx = np.unravel_index(np.argmin(val, axis=None), val.shape)
    max_val_ndx = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(val, axis=None), val.shape)

    cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'chartreuse', 'limegreen'])
    ax = sns.heatmap(val, xticklabels=x, yticklabels=y, cmap=cmap, annot=True, fmt='.2f')

    ax.add_patch(Rectangle(min_val_ndx[::-1], 1, 1, fill=False, edgecolor='blue', lw=3, clip_on=False))
    ax.add_patch(Rectangle(max_val_ndx[::-1], 1, 1, fill=False, edgecolor='blue', lw=3, clip_on=False))
```

`data_a` works, `data_b` doesn't.
I think I figured out why (there is not enough data to fill the whole matrix).
So how to increase the size of the data chunks so the heatmap will be created?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [76]: data = np.array(data_a)
In [77]: data
Out[77]: 
array([[2.700000e+01, 6.000000e+00, 9.944930e+03, 9.944930e+03],
       [1.760000e+02, 3.000000e+01, 1.634547e+04, 1.634547e+04],
       [2.510000e+02, 1.800000e+01, 1.424278e+04, 1.424278e+04],
       [1.020000e+02, 4.200000e+01, 1.708514e+04, 1.708514e+04]])
In [78]: x = np.unique(data[:,1])
In [79]: x
Out[79]: array([ 6., 18., 30., 42.])
In [80]: y = np.unique(data[:,0])
In [81]: y
Out[81]: array([ 27., 102., 176., 251.])
In [82]: data[:,3]
Out[82]: array([ 9944.93, 16345.47, 14242.78, 17085.14])
```

`Out[82]` has 4 elements; obviously it can't be reshaped to 16 elements as required by (4,4).

What are you trying to accomplish with this reshape?

Comment: I would like to create a heatmap with my data. So i thought I somehow extend my array with 0 in advance to reshape it then?